# Struts (Java), changing forward name for an action that takes input parameter=page doesn't let me access that page at new name

Tags: java, apache, struts, struts-1

I'm still fairly new to Struts (for a legacy project for current employer), in this case I am using Struts 1 so not sure if that matters.

I am trying to edit an action that has a bunch of forwards but for simplicity I have just included one. This particular forward just maps to a static JSP and can normally be accessed without having to login to the application.

So normally this page is accessed at (assuming I'm running this locally):

```
https://localhost/sc.do?page=download
```

The forward is set as:

```
<forward name="download" path=".downloadPage"/>
```

Now all I tried doing was changing the name `download` to something else (in the forward below), such as `downloadtest`, I made sure to rebuild it, etc and relaunched, now I cannot access it at

`https://localhost/sc.do?page=download` but neither can I access the page at: `https://localhost/sc.do?page=downloadtest`

I'm really confused as to what else there would be in a configuration file that would prevent this from working, I have been reading tutorials and from my understanding this should work. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
      <action path="/sc"
              type="com.somecompany.wa.actions.PageDispatchAction"
              name="scAdminForm"
              parameter="page">

        <set-property property="secure" value="true"/>

        <forward name="downloadtest" path=".downloadPage"/>
</action>
```

This is the com.somecompany.wa.actions.PageDispatchAction class:

```
public class PageDispatchAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ActionContext context = new ActionContext(mapping, form, request, response);
        Command command = new CheckPageSecurityCommand();
        boolean stop = command.execute(context);
        if (stop) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return (ActionForward) context.get("forward");
        }
    }

    // redirects control to logout page
    // calls to this method should be followed by return null or end of method.
    protected void redirectToLogout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ServletWebContext context = new ServletWebContext(request.getSession(true).getServletContext(), request, response);
        Command command = new RedirectToLogoutCommand();
        command.execute(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more familiar with Struts 1.2 and what you have here looks like Struts 1.3, but I was surprised to see that `PageDispatchAction` didn't extend `DispatchAction` instead of `Action`. Typically, when you define the `parameter` attribute of an `action` in `struts-config.xml` the `type` refers to a subclass of `DispatchAction`. This indicates that whatever value for `page` is supplied in the request would map to a method in the action of the same name with the way things are defined here. So `page=download` would map to a `download` method in `PageDispatchAction`. Anyway, I'm not sure how what you have here is working since to my eye it looks like the return is looking for an `ActionForward` called `forward`. Perhaps it is my Struts 1.2 bias though and 1.3 works differently. Not sure.

Comment: Yes, it is Struts 1.3. I read through your post a couple times and I see what you mean but it seems this is not the case for much of the application as they are somehow making these page parameters map to JSP's without having a method for that page. In this particular action that I mentioned in my original post, it actually has 50+ forwards that go to various JSP's (using tiles so some are made up of more than 1 JSP) and this is all done through the one class I posted above.